# Accesing variables declared in JAVASCRIPT in a different HTML FILE

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files screen.html and db_fun.js.
I have declared a variable at just the beginning as follows:

> db_fun.js
>   var name = "abc";

now i tried to access this variable in the screen.html file as follows

> screen.html

```
<html> 
 <body> 
   <form name = "screen" action = "db_fun.js"> 
        <p> <script>document.write(name);</script> </p>
   </form>
 </body>  
 <script src="db_fun.js" type="text/javascript" />
</html>
```

it doesn't print nethn. Y so?

Comment: What's the point of setting the form's action to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="db_fun.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are inserting your JavaScript in the page footer. You have to firstly load your javascript file into your web site (in the head section for example) and then use your variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should move

```
<script src="db_fun.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

In the head of the page. I.e. before document.write.
Because in the moment where you are trying to print 'name', the variable is still not created. Also I think that it is not a very good practice to use document.write to add content to your page. Try using jQuery or some other library. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("p").html(name);
});
```

Comment: ohk, did that. but the thing is that if i am taking an array say suppose
**var arr = new Array(20);**
and i declare it as the first line in my .js file, then later in a functions i am assigning values to it, now if i try to access those values outside that function, it says "undefined". Y so? isn't the array that i declared global?

Comment: @wOlVeRiNe your above comment, now please could explain what on earth are trying to do or accomplish?

Comment: The following code works for me: var arr = [];
   function test() {
    arr.push(20);
    arr.push(30);
    arr.push(40);
   }
   test();
   console.log(arr); // prints out [20, 30, 40]

Comment: i got the answer, :p it was a silly mistake, i was using callbacks, and was accesing the array after the callback method. hence it was saying undefined. Thanks neways guys