# using an array in a html file

Tags: javascript, html

An array of objects is stored in a JavaScript file. let's say the size of this array is 3000.

```
students = [_size];
students = [data1, data2, data3, data4,...datan];
```

*File is saved with ".js" extension.*

Now because this array is pretty large, I would like to save it on a different file (data1.js) and access this file in my html file where the data will be used on a map. The objects on the array contain latitude and longitude coordinates.

I searched online and used this link: [Accesing variables declared in JAVASCRIPT in a different HTML FILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722821/accesing-variables-declared-in-javascript-in-a-different-html-file)

The problem is: In the html file, if I try to call the variable that holds the objects, it shows me that all the fields are available. E.g when i use the dot operator `students[5].`, I can see all the fields that belong to the object. But when I use this array and try to iterate or copy it to a new array, it doesn't work. Basically anytime I call this array in my html file, my map doesn't load correctly.

1. How can I copy this whole array to the html file where I will be loading the map?

## code#:

*data1.js*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

students = [_size];
students = [ {"ZIP_CODE":852,"Lat":32.063704,"Long":-107.835308},
{"ZIP_CODE":1752,"Lat":42.347372,"Long":-71.536786},
{"ZIP_CODE":2649,"Lat":41.617748,"Long":-70.514594},
{"ZIP_CODE":3031,"Lat":42.870824,"Long":-71.608001} ]; </script>
```

*app.html*

```
<script 
type = "text/javascript" src="C:/Users/doc/project/data1.js">
</script>
```

*how i use the array in the .html file

```
    var marker;
    for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    var thisLatLng = {lat: (students[i].Lat), lng: (students[i].Long)};
          
   //Create marker object for a map
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: thisLatLng,
          icon: r_image,
          map: map                        
    });
```

Comment: is that script tag inside `data.js`? If so it doesn't belong there. remove it

Comment: btw `students = [_size];` does not create an array of size `_size`, it creates an array with the first element being `_size`

Comment: Few problems with your code... 1. The inclusion of `<script type="text/javascript">` in data1.js would prevent it from working. You don't need that inside a js file. 2. Your excerpt of js code is missing a `}` which will also stop it from working. 3. Where does your excerpt of js code appear in the HTML file? It needs to appear after the `<script>` tag that links to the data, in order to access that data. 4. It will be helpful if you can mention what error is raised. (check the browser's console)

Answer (score 0):

The best practise would be to have a `JSON` file and retrieve data using JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment. But, You can store all your data in a JSON file and then make requests to retrieve data as and when needed. Hope that helps!